# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error when running Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying work through a hive tutorial in which I enter the following:

```
load data local inpath '/usr/local/Cellar/hive/0.11.0/libexec/examples/files/kv1.txt' overwrite into table pokes;
```

Thits results in the following error:

```
FAILED: RuntimeException java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I see that there  are some replies on SA having to do with configuring my ip address and local host, but I'm not familiar with the concepts in the answers.  I'd appreciate anything you can tell me about the fundamentals of what causes this kind of answer and how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because hive is not able to contact your `namenode`

Check if your `hadoop` services has started properly.

Run the command `jps` to see what all services are running.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  From $jps I just get: "26349 Jps".

Comment: that means none of your hadoop services are running. have you configured hadoop?

Comment: Thanks.  I think I figured it out -- when you fire up hive, you must first run the start-all.sh script, correct?  Once I did that, I got the full roster of jps services and the ConnectException went away.  I had misread the start-all.sh as something to be done just once during the initial setup.

Comment: you are right :) start-all will start all the hadoop services. I would suggest you to start namenode and datanode separately and run start-mapred.sh. In that way you can easily see what is happening in these nodes. This will help you debugging.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you get this error is that Hive needs hadoop as its base. So, you need to start Hadoop first.

Here are some steps.

Step1: download hadoop and unzip it

Step2: cd #your_hadoop_path

Step3: ./bin/hadoop namenode -format

Step4: ./sbin/start-all.sh

And then, go back to #your_hive_path and start hive again

Comment: one does not simply install hadoop in 4 steps LOL

Answer (score 0):

Easy way i found to edit the /etc/hosts file. default it looks like

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    user_user_name
```

just edit and make 127.0.1.1 to 127.0.0.1 thats it , restart your shell  and restart your cluster by start-all.sh

Answer (score 0):

same question when set up hive. 
solved by change my /etc/hostname

formerly it is my user_machine_name
after I changed it to localhost, then it went well

I guess it is because hadoop may want to resolve your hostname using this /etc/hostname file, but it directed it to your user_machine_name while the hadoop service is running on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by executing the below command:

```
start-all.sh
```

This would ensure that the Hive service has started.

Then starting the Hive was straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a connection timeout:

```
WARN DFSClient: Failed to connect to /10.165.0.27:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
```

DFSClient was resolving nodes by internal IP. Here's the solution for this:

```
.config("spark.hadoop.dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname", "true")
```